# Monic polynomial of degree $p$ of which all reductions mod $q\leq p$ are irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that there exists a monic polynomial $f\in \mathbf{Z}[x]$ of degree $p$ such that
>
> - for all primes $q\leq p$, the reduction $\overline{f}\in \mathbf{F}_q[x]$ is irreducible.

I am looking for **a hint**. It may use abstract algebra, Galois theory..

Most of the time I can manage finite fields pretty well, but here I am clueless. I know that any monic irreducible polynomial of degree $p$ in $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$ is a divisor of $X^{q^p}-X$ in $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$. I also thought of taking an Artin-Schreier polynomial $X^p-X+a\in \mathbf{F}_p[x]$ to begin with an irreducible polynomial of degree $p$ in $\mathbf{F}_p[X]$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With $p_j$ the $j$-th prime, given some polynomials $f_j \bmod p_j$ there is some $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ whose reduction is $f\equiv f_j \bmod p_j$ for all $j\le J$ (chinese remainder theorem)

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the hint, this enabled me to continue!